# how to convert string to datetime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Session variable in which i have stored one date '22/7/2009'.Now i want to convert value in session to datetime. I tried folowing code:

```
Session("AppointmentDate") = Request.QueryString("ADate")
Dim s as datetime=Convert.ToDateTime(Session("AppointmentDate"))
```

But error is showing as 'string is not recognized as a valid datetime'.
Can anybody help me to convert value in Session to date?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you put the value *into* the session as a DateTime?

Failing that, use :-

Use :-

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
  myDateString, 
  "d/M/yyyy",     
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

Where myDateString contains your value from Session["AppointmentDate"]

Comment: Technically, your fist suggestion just moves the issue up a bit, if the querystring is "22/7/2009" then calling Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString("ADate")) wouldn't be any different ;)

Comment: Agreed :) Gotta parse sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx) to specify the date format string. I think it'd be something like:

```
 dateValue = Date.ParseExact(dateString, "d", frFR, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

or

```
 dateValue = Date.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/M/yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to store your date as `22/07/2009` so that `Convert.ToDateTime()` could recognize it.